# how to realize several answers in quiz?

Tags: ios, testing, plist

I have created a quiz with 4 answers and one of them is right answer. Questions and answers I keep in plist.( where It have arrays of dictionaries).
Now I want to have more than one right answer to one question. Example: User can select A  B C D  or A C or B C D etc. and push button "next question".
Please tell me the right way to realize my mission!

Sorry for my ENG, I am Russian.

m.file

```
enter code here- (void)showNextQuestion
    {
if ([self.highScore integerForKey:@"HighScore"]<numCorrect){
    [self.highScore setInteger:numCorrect forKey:@"HighScore"];
    [self.highScore synchronize]; 
}

currentQuestion++; //= arc4random()%10;
if (currentQuestion <= [self.questions count]){

    self.labelScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numCorrect];
    self.labelHighestScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self.highScore integerForKey:@"HighScore"]];

    NSDictionary* nextQuestion = [self.questions objectAtIndex: currentQuestion];//[self.questions objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentQuestion]];
    NSString* correctAnswer = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"CorrectAnswer"];
    self.answer = correctAnswer;

    self.labelA.text = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"A"];
    self.labelB.text = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"B"];
    self.labelC.text = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"C"];
    self.labelD.text = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"D"];


    self.labelQuestion.text = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"QuestionTitle"];
    NSLog(@"%d количество вопросов", countQuestion);

    int questNumber = countQuestion+1;

            NSString *questNumberString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",                 questNumber];
    NSLog(@"%@", questNumberString);

    questNum.text = questNumberString;


    - (IBAction)buttonPressedA:(id)sender {
  //AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID1);
   countQuestion++;
        if([self.answer isEqualToString: @"A" ]){
    numCorrect += 1;

    self.labelScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numCorrect];
        }
        [self showNextQuestion];
    }

    - (IBAction)buttonPressedB:(id)sender {
 // AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID1);
 countQuestion++;
if([self.answer isEqualToString: @"B"]){
    numCorrect += 1;

    self.labelScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numCorrect];
        }

        [self showNextQuestion];}

    - (IBAction)buttonPressedC:(id)sender {
  //AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID1);
 countQuestion++;
if([self.answer isEqualToString: @"C"]){
    numCorrect += 1;

    self.labelScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numCorrect];
}
[self showNextQuestion];}

       - (IBAction)buttonPressedD:(id)sender {
  //AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID1);
        countQuestion++;
    if([self.answer isEqualToString: @"D"]){
        numCorrect += 1;

        self.labelScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numCorrect];
    }

        [self showNextQuestion];}
    @end
```

Comment: Show the code that you have for your single selection answers. How do you know which question has multiple answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your plist, make the answer itself a dictionary. Use one key/value pair for the title and the other one to indicate if it is correct or not.

[image]

When the user selects an answer, you just have to check the corresponding boolean value (in this case "correct").

Comment: please, can you write more detailed answer or give a useful link, thanks!

Comment: What part did you not understand?

Comment: I have Item 0,1,2... in witch i have keys "QuestionTitle", "A" "B" "C" "D", "CorrectAnswer" its all type string. I should change "CorectAnswer" into type dictionary?

Comment: I would suggest the following: Get rid of "Correct Answer". Instead, change "A", "B", "C" and "D" into a Dictionary. This dictionary should have two key/value pairs. "title" -> String and "correct" -> Boolean.

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand  thats what I have http://postimg.org/image/qzbaya9ab/   can you sent a scrin with the right way changes.

Comment: thanks a lot for help,If I have not bored you, then, what I should do in m. file?

Comment: I am glad, if I can push you in the right direction, however I will not do your work for you. In the .m file, at the point where you previously read out the title of the question directly, you will now get an NSDictionary instead. When the user selects an option, just check the "correct"-object of the answers dictionary.

Comment: thanks a lot I'll try all your advices.Here is my app look like http://postimg.org/image/eiamazibn/ there are computer test in my university and I want to make ios app of that tests. Have you WHATS UP? It will be awesome if we will be able to connect and discuss ios development